# Embed Windows Media Player in a PyGTK application

Tags: windows, pygtk, windows-media-player

Is there any way to display videos in a PyGTK application using Windows Media Player? I'm trying to play SopCast streams in a PyGTK application and currently I'm doing that by embedding Internet Explorer and showing an webpage containing a Windows Media Player control, but I need a better way to do this.

Also, I'm wondering if I can access the SopCast's OCX, starting the stream from there and then playing it using VLC (this would be better) by opening the localhost stream which SopCast creates.

Thank you